# Wordpress post pagination on custom template not working

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, pagination

I've copied the code from the Wordpress documentation on adding pagination to a custom query using `'paged' => $paged`. However, on my page it's not working. What am i doing wrong??

```
  <?php 
      $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
      $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged); 
      $the_query = new WP_query($args); 
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?> 
        <ul class="pis-ul">
      <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
           <li class="pis-li">
                 <a class="pis-title-link" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                 <div class="news-thumbnail">

                 <?php

                    if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                     echo the_post_thumbnail('news-thumbnail');  
                    }

                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <p class="pis-title">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>       
                    </p>
                    <p class="pis-excerpt">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="pis-utlility">
                        <span class="pis-date">Published on <?php echo the_date(); ?></span>
                    </p>
                 </a>     
            </li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
        <ul>
      <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
      <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

      <?php else:  ?>
        <p>
          <?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: "not working" is vague. What is/isn't happening, and what do you expect/want to happen?

Comment: Not working meaning the next and previous buttons aren't showing up. I want them to display so i can go to the next page of posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next_post_link` will use the current query (which is the global `$wp_query` in your case). If you want to use them with other queries, pass them the maximum page number as the second argument. There's an [example in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query).

For `previous_post_link` it doesn't matter, because it'll only show a link if you're on a page other than the first - and if you are, there has to be a previous page. The link will show up when the `paged` parameter is > 1.